# ¿Como cambiar el color de fondo de una JTable en java?

Tags: java

Quiero cambiar el color gris que tiene una `JTable` por defecto en netbeans.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Suele ser conveniente mostrar una porción de tu código que sea reproducible para que las respuestas sean más acertadas

Answer (score 3):

En general deberías poder cambiar el color de fondo con

```
Color myColor = new Color(255,255,208);
table.setBackground(myColor);
```

Pero dependiendo de como esté realmente tu código esto puedo no funcionar directamente. Si tienes la tabla dentro de `JScrollPane` y le has dicho que la tabla llene el panel con un código de este tipo:

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

Tendrás que cambiar el color del ViewPort

```
scroll.getViewport().setBackground(myColor);
```

Esto puede variar un poco dependiendo de si has definido la tabla como opaca o no (`table.setOpaque(false);`), pero jugando con estas variables deberías poder cambiar el background